# Is it better to build a colony on the moon or mars

Tags: space-colonization, colonies

What planet would be most efficient place to build a colony on?

There is a lot of debate whether  would be better on the Moon or on Mars.

The main problem is time. with the available funds you could build a semi self-sufficient on the Moon in 15-50 years. Or you could build a self sufficient on Mars in 25-65. That's if everything goes well but still realistic.

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion depending on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What's the measure of "efficient"?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by efficient, and what the goals of the colony are?  I would expect permanent lunar and Martian colonies to have different purposes, which would make it hard to decide which works better if we don't know the goals.  Thanks.  The community has put this question on hold temporarily, but if you [edit] in some details it'll be reviewed for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

Define self-sufficient... If that includes trading with Earth, then the moons the best bet. It's closer, to the motherland so transit time is considerably less and regular visits home are feasible. Setting up on Mars is a lifetime commitment for almost everyone that makes the journey.

The moons got a shallower gravity well, its closer to the sun (solar energy), it's got some water reserves and its very close to soggy ole Earth.

It'd be easier to terraform Mars than the moon but that's a long term investment and you said time is of the essence. Providing you don't mind your colonists living under domes or underground and if you'll accept trade as an element of self sufficiency then 20 years or so seems reasonable.

Comment: I mean it can survive with out interaction with any thing else.

Comment: Mars isn't only the easier of the two to terraform, it's the only one of the two you might be able to terraform, the moon is simply too small, there's just not enough gravity to hold an atmosphere thick enough to be worthy of the name, no atmosphere, no terraforming, domes is all you can do on the moon.